# Automator: How to copy the contents of local folder to a linux smb share?

Tags: macos, automator, file-sharing, smb, folder-action

I use Lion and I'm trying to make a folder action that copies the content of a local folder to a **Samba** share, but when I execute the action at **Automator** it copies the folder and not only its contents to the remote location.

I created a new **Folder Action** and used the **Copy Finder Items** with the **Replace Existing Files** checked.
What did I do wrong?

[image: Folder Action 1]
I also have another version with **Get Specified Server** and **Connect To Server** actions before the **Copy Finder Items** to connect the server when it is note mounted. At least I think this is correct.
[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the Automator action you use for copying?

Comment: Well, I can do that but my system is in Brazilian Portuguese. Wouldn't it be a problem?